# ASP.NET Web.Config Transformation Issue

Tags: .net, asp.net, authentication, web-config, web-config-transform

How can I use a `web.config` transform to include the domain attribute in my production `web.config`?

I have the following in my base `web.config`.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

I have tried to use the following in my `web.prod.config`, but it doesn't add the attribute when I publish the project.

```
<authentication mode="Forms" xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" domain=".mydomain.com" />
</authentication>
```

I would like the output to be the following.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" domain=".mydomain.com"/>
</authentication>
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with your question but is the domain really `=".mydomain.com"` instead of `="mydomain.com"`... is the period supposed to be in there?

Comment: Thanks, yes the dot is supposed to be there, this will be catering for a sub domain, but many thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7):

One of these two should work (untested, but based on [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx)):

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(forms)">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" domain=".mydomain.com" />
  </authentication>
</system.web>

<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms domain=".mydomain.com" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(domain)" />
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay with the reply for this. I will try out your solution this evening an let you know. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You can test config transformations using this tool: http://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/

Comment: Also, this needs to be inside <system.web>

Comment: @kmdsax you are my hero, after doing that the above answer worked. John Pick can you update your wanswer to include this important detail?

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the entire config I can't confirm this will work, but I would try adding a locator to make sure its grabbing that line and doing the transform.

So instead of just

```
<authentication mode="Forms" xdt:Transform="Replace">
```

Which will match anything like this in this path

Try

```
<authentication mode="Forms" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(mode)">
```

which will explicitly pick up an auth node at that xpath, where the mode = Forms, which should yield 1 and only 1 match to the transform engine and do the replacement.

If that doesn't work, I'd reverse a bit to see if its transforming at all (which I doubt), by changing the loginUrl ni the transform just to see if it comes out the other side.

Chances are you are getting a transform error somewhere and its just not applying.

Comment: Sorry for the delay with the reply for this. I will try out your solution this evening an let you know. Many thanks for your help.